# Is it possible to use symbolic links in Virtualbox shared folder without administrator priviledges?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Is it possible to have Unix guest on Windows 10 host and use symbolic links in Virtualbox shared folders *without* administrator priviledges?

I'm asking because previously symbolic links on Windows 10 required administator priviledges but [now it's possible](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/#iE3YzfWU3pdJDz8d.97) to enable *Developer mode* to create symbolic links using standard account and `mklink`. Thus it make sense there would be a way use the Developer mode to lift the administrator requirement on symbolic links in shared folders as well.

Comment: SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege doesn't require administrator access. If it's provided only by administrator access, then it gets filtered out of the token for a non-elevated UAC logon. But an administrator can grant it to a user, group, or well-known group such as "Authenticated Users", in which case it won't be filtered out.

Comment: Thanks eryksun. Giving a user SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege doesn't even require the _Developer mode_. The only issue is that my user account is in administrator group so I would need to create another account and then switch back and forth between the new and the current account.

Comment: I grant the privilege to "Authenticated Users". Everyone that logs on with credentials is in this group. With this in place, an administrator doesn't have to elevate to create symbolic links.

Comment: My computer is a single user laptop not connected to a domain, so wouldn't that mean I'd need to create a second account which is not in Administrator group and that would then get the priviledge granted to "Authenticated Users"? But then every time I need admin priviledges I would need to switch to the other admin account. This doesn't sound very convenient or am I missing something here?

Comment: Run `whoami /groups` to see what groups your account has and what state they're in. Run it non-elevated and elevated, and compare. You should have the "Authenticated Users" group (S-1-5-11) enabled in both cases.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer is yes. It is possible to use symbolic links in Virtualbox shared folders without administrator priviledges and it doesn't even require the *Developer Mode*.

Here are the step-by-step instructions how to do it, thanks eryksun for helping me out!

1. Launch *Local Security Policy* app from start menu (or Win+R, then type `secpol.msc`)
2. Navigate to *Local Policies* -> *User Rights Assignment*
3. Open *Create symbolic links* property. By default it has only *Administrators* listed.
4. Click *Add User or Group...* and write **Authenticated Users** to the *Enter the object names to select* field to grant the symbolic link priviledge to all users who log on with credetials
5. Close the windows by clicking OKs and log off and log on
6. Now symbolic links are working in VirtualBox shared folders without administrator priviledges!

[image: Instructions how to grant the symbolic links priviledge]

The *Developer Mode* didn't help here even though it enables the use of symbolic links without elevated access in two ways:

1. `mklink` command can be used without elevated access
2. CreateSymbolicLink API can be used without elevated access *if* you pass dwFlags option `SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_ALLOW_UNPRIVILEGED_CREATE`

Since even after enabling the *Developer Mode* VirtualBox has to be run as Administrator in order to create symlinks I assume the method 2 i.e. API calls are used to create the symlinks. Thus VirtualBox code would need to be updated to use the `SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_ALLOW_UNPRIVILEGED_CREATE` flag. After that update enabling *Developer Mode* should be sufficient to enable symbolic links in shared folders.

Comment: The Windows API added `SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_ALLOW_UNPRIVILEGED_CREATE` so applications can selectively enable it, but it's annoying to use because it's an invalid parameter in older versions of Windows. I'd prefer either an opt-in manifest setting or API call to allow creating unprivileged symlinks in developer mode, rather than providing the option on a per-call basis.

Comment: Also note that when you are using shared folders in this way, the symbolic link is resolved by the *host,* not the *guest.*  VirtualBox hands the request over to the host's filesystem.

Comment: Samuli Asmala, this might not work for Windows 10 **Home**. I added to your [ticket #18680](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18680#comment:1) in the hopes that the VirtualBox team can work out a trivial fix for this.

Comment: Just allowing Authenticated Users to create links was not enough for me. It was also  needed to execute command on the host: `VBoxManage.exe setextradata "MyVM" VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/MyShare 1` to enable creating links on specific share. See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#:~:text=SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate for more